# Pivot a table with Amazon RedShift

Tags: sql, pivot, amazon-redshift, paraccel

I have several tables in Amazon RedShift that follow the pattern of several dimension columns and a pair of metric name/value columns.

```
DimensionA  DimensionB  MetricName  MetricValue
----------  ----------  ----------  -----------
dimA1       dimB1       m1          v11
dimA1       dimB2       m1          v12
dimA1       dimB2       m2          v21
dimA2       dimB2       m1          v13
dimA3       dimB1       m2          v22
```

I am looking for a good way to unwind/pivot the data into a form of one row per each unique dimension set, e.g.:

```
DimensionA  DimensionB  m1   m2 
----------  ----------  ---  ---
dimA1       dimB1       v11
dimA1       dimB2       v12  v21
dimA2       dimB2       v13
dimA3       dimB1            v22
```

What is a good pattern for generating queries that would perform this unwinding?

Amazon RedShift is based on ParAccel and supports PostgreSQL 8.0.2, which does not have `crosstab`, `unnest`, `pivot` or `unpivot`.

Comment: What you are looking for is Pivot. I am editing the question accordingly

Comment: Alternative method supporting arbitrary groups is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42687221/3019685

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just create a CASE statement per MetricName but you'll have to use an aggregate as well to make the GROUP BY work.

```
SELECT dimension_a
      ,dimension_b
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN metric_name = 'm1' THEN metric_value ELSE NULL END) m1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN metric_name = 'm2' THEN metric_value ELSE NULL END) m2
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY dimension_a
         ,dimension_b
;
```

Worth noting that Redshift object names are never case sensitive but column content always is, which is the opposite of SQL Server defaults.