# Pivot query by date in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a table in Redshift like:

```
category | date
----------------
   1     | 9/29/2016
   1     | 9/28/2016
   2     | 9/28/2016
   2     | 9/28/2016
```

which I'd like to turn into:

```
category | 9/29/2016 | 2/28/2016
--------------------------------
   1     |    1      |   1 
   2     |    0      |   2
```

(count of each category for each date)

[Pivot a table with Amazon RedShift / PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650918/pivot-a-table-with-amazon-redshift-postgresql) seems to be helpful using CASE statements but that requires knowing all possible cases beforehand - how could I do this if the columns I want are every day starting from a given date?

Answer (score 3):

There is **no functionality** provided with Amazon Redshift that can automatically pivot the data.

The [Pivot a table with Amazon RedShift / PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650918/pivot-a-table-with-amazon-redshift-postgresql) page you referenced shows how the output can be generated, but it is unable to automatically adjust the number of columns based upon the input data.

One option would be to **write a program** that queries available date ranges, then generates the SQL query. However, this isn't possible totally within Amazon Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a self join on date, which i'm currently looking up how to do.