# how to join with complecated condition in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have following table1

```
id name
1  A
3  B
```

and table2

```
id label value
1   a    10
1   b    11
1   c    12
2   a    13
2   b    14
2   c    15 
3   a    16 
3   b    17
3   c    18
```

My desired result is following.I'd like to join table1 and table2 in `label=a and b`
I guess I must join twice in each condition..

```
id name a    b
1   A   10   11
3   B   16   17
```

I tried following one, but I get only result in `label = a`

```
select *
from table1
left join table2 using(id)
where label in ('a')
```

Are there any good way to achieve this?
I guess we need transpose

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift doesn't have a native pivot function so you need to do it using a case statement:

```
SELECT
    table1.id,
    table1.name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN table2.label = 'a' THEN table2.value END) AS a,
    SUM(CASE WHEN table2.label = 'b' THEN table2.value END) AS b
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id
GROUP BY table1.id, table1.name
```

See this link also:
[Pivot for redshift database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694134/pivot-for-redshift-database)